# Ubuntu 20.04 with QGIS 3.14 (pi) SAGA is missing

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, saga

After updating to QGIS 3.14 in Ubuntu 20.04, SAGA is not available. The Log Panel (View->Panels->Log Messages) said SAGA didn't load. In the Processing Toolbox, the SAGA category is missing.

Answer (score 7):

In order to solve the problem I had to:

1. Verify if SAGA is actually installed in the system with:

`saga_cmd`

It said SAGA was not installed.

2. Install SAGA with:

`sudo apt-get install saga`

3. Check it's version with:

`saga_cmd`

Answer was: "SAGA Version: 7.3.0"

4. Edit the ***SagaAlgorithmProvider.py*** file:

`sudo nano /usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/algs/saga/SagaAlgorithmProvider.py`

5. Replaced REQUIRED_VERSION = '2.3.' with REQUIRED_VERSION = '7.3.'
6. Save file (Ctrl-O) and quit nano (Ctrl-X).
7. Run QGIS 3.14

Now SAGA is available in the Processing Toolbox!!! When running and algorithm it says "SAGA version 7.3.0 is not officially supported - algorithms may encounter issues", yet I have not found any issues.